# More about for loops

Tags: c, for-loop

I was testing some code and here is a strange thing I found:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{int m,n;
  for(m=0, n=0; m<0,n<4; m++,n++)
  printf("hello\n");
 }
```

My guess was that it wouldn't do print because the condition `m<0` isn't satisfied. But I was shocked with this:

#### Output

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

Can anyone explain this result. Why didn't the `m<0` condition get evaluated?

Comment: Google "comma operator". `,` is not `&&`.

Comment: Also, `main()` returns `int`.

Comment: @H2CO3 It does not matter if you put void or int. **Try it**

Comment: @user689 C11 §5.1.2.2.1 p 1: *"The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` [...]"*

Comment: @kninnug nice to know that. I learned it the wrong way. But in a simple program like this it is legal to use void (in c language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C (and many other languages), the comma operator is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns the result of the 2nd operand.

So `cond1, cond2` evaluates both conditions but only `cond2` matters.

If you want both conditions to be satisfied, use `cond1 && cond2`.
So

```
for(m=0, n=0; m<0 && n<4; m++,n++)
```

Comment: So to fix this I should use && ?

Answer (score 2):

What you meant was `m < 0 && n < 4`.

The `,` operator takes two expressions, executes both of them (ie, for potential side-effects), but evaluates to the result of the *second* expression. So `m < 0, n < 4` evaluates `m < 0` (which has no side-effects, so it might as well not be there), discards the value `false`, and returns `n < 4`.

Answer (score 1):

It get evaluated but the comma operator `,` will discard the effect of the condition `m<0`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `m<0` did get evaluated, but due to the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) its result was discarded and the result of the next expression: `n<4` was used for the `for`-condition instead.

As mentioned: the expression `m < 0 && n < 4` will also evaluate both sub-expressions but only return true when they are both true.